# Does Linux have device drivers for USB ports?

Tags: linux, drivers, usb, serial-port

This is the device driver for *serial port 1*: `/dev/ttyS1`.

Is there a device driver for a USB port, or does USB works in a much complicated way that a USB port can't be represented using a single file?

Comment: USB in general is complicated and uses multiple modules ("drivers"), while there is a single module ("driver") for USB serial port devices that follow the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/dev/ttyS1` is a device *node* for the *second* serial port.

USB serial ports also get device nodes, they’re usually called `/dev/ttyUSB0` and so on. Some USB devices will allocate two nodes (*e.g.* `/dev/ttyUSB0` and `/dev/ttyUSB1`; old USB Palm devices do this). Some USB serial devices which act more like a modem will have a `/dev/ttyACM0` device node instead.

The actual device drivers are in the kernel, often provided as kernel modules. On PCs using 8250-style serial ports, the driver is `tty/serial/8250/serial_cs.ko`. For USB serial ports, it will be one of the drivers in `usb/serial`. (Both paths are relative to `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers`.)